Undefine CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP macro while building linux kernel image
I am wanted to build a custom kernel image in which macro CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP is not defined. After researching a little bit I found we can do such configurations in .config file.
To be more precise I am building custom kernel image in CentOS8-Stream and the only documentation available is at https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos(2f)Custom_Kernel.html
Following the documentation as mentioned in above link I started building custom kernel kernel-4.18.0-448.el8.src.rpm.
In step 2 configuring the kernel I copied the config to root kernel source tree as:
# cp configs/kernel-4.18.0-`uname -m`.config .config
Then did:
# make oldconfig
Then edited the config and unset CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP using menuconfig:
# make menuconfig
CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP setting is available in menuconfig under:
General setup -> Control Group support -> IO controller
as I found by searching for CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP in menuconfig UI.
I changed the check box from [*] to empty [ ] and saved the changes.
Then when I verified the file .config I could see line:
# CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP is not set in .config file.
Then followed the rest steps and issued the build as below:
# rpmbuild -bb --without debug --target=`uname -m` kernel.spec 2> build-err.log | tee build-out.log
Now what I notice after build is that,

the file include/generated/autoconf.h still has line #define CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP 1
Even after installing the custom kernel and re-booting into it I could see CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y in config file under /boot/config<kernel_version>

Then later I also tried multiple attempts to do the steps as mentioned in CentOS guide again but in a little different way like by changing all the config files under configs dir manually by updating CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y to # CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP is not set on step 2 after doing make menuconfig
Then just followed next steps as in guide still no luck I still line #define CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP 1 in autoconf.h.
Any insights on this, need a way such that my kernel compiles without defining CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP. Basically I don't want the linux kernel source code falling under #ifdef CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP to be executed.
